# how to get the file name from image path

Tags: ios, swift4

i am trying to get the file name from image pathurl
but i am getting an error like "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to type 'NSString' in coercion"can anyone help me to convert as NSstring .Thanks in advance

```
if var imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL{
    let imgName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let localPath = documentDirectory?.appending(imgName)

    var image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
    let data = image.pngData()! as NSData
    data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
    //let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath!)!
    let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)//NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)
    print(photoURL)

    let filename = (photoURL as NSString).lastPathComponent
    // pdfURL is your file url
    let fileExtention = (filename as NSString).pathExtension  // get your file extension
    let pathPrefix = (filename as NSString).deletingPathExtension
    img.image = image
```

Answer (score 4):

(In Swift) all methods for path manipulation are in the URL struct. No conversion needed

```
let filename = photoURL.lastPathComponent
// pdfURL is your file url
let fileExtention = photoURL.pathExtension  // get your file extension
let pathPrefix = photoURL.deletingPathExtension.lastPathComponent
img.image = image
```

And don't use `NS` classes in Swift at all if there is a native equivalent.

---

And please consider warnings like

> Variable 'image' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

Comment: can we get mime type from  URL.??

Comment: No, but from an HTTP response